# Image is not uploading to the specific destination

Tags: python, django

I tried several ways to upload images to a specific destination. Showing no error but the image is not uploading to the destination.

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['name', 'weblink', 'image']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts')
    template_name = 'base/post.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    weblink = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Added {self.name} Profile'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    .....
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**template**

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row justify-content-md-center home">
    <div class="col-md-6 create-form">
         <a href="{% url 'posts' %}">&#8592; Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 submit-form">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <button class="btn btn-info"  type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
    
{% endblock content %}
```

I added also the media root and URL in the settings file. I didn't any clue but unable to upload the file to the specific location.

Comment: What do you mean "unable to upload the file to the specific location." does it get saved somewhere else, or is it not saved at all? Show your template.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat not it doesn't upload at all. Check update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your form is supposed to submit files you must set the `enctype` attribute on the form tag to `multipart/form-data` otherwise files won't be submitted:

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row justify-content-md-center home">
    <div class="col-md-6 create-form">
         <a href="{% url 'posts' %}">&#8592; Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 submit-form">
        <!--                              Set it here ↓          -->
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <button class="btn btn-info"  type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
    
{% endblock content %}
```